# How to access webpage held down by anchor and loop statements

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, anchor, void

I have to access a webpage that only is available during a certain time window.

The button is held down by anchor tags and java voids, I have no idea how to get around this to get to the webpage.

[image: This]

This is the button that leads to the [next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdgJj.png) pop-up that says you cannot take this assessment:

[image: Next]

When I  [inspected the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teNoQ.jpg) on Chrome, the following code is seen.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary assessemnt_take_btn" aid="10177753745ef8bda622317" sg="1585548315cd664d17c56b">Take Assessment</a>
```

[image]

It is within anchor tags.

A previous button of the same style I clicked during the time frame and afterwards, the "Take Assessment" button changed to a "View Result" button which opens the web page I originally intended to go to.

The [Inspecting of this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAgrG.jpg) of this button turned up the following code with a javascript:void(0) statement

```
<a class="btn btn-success assessemnt_result_btn" aid="19832479115ef8a44d2b8c2" sg="1585548315cd664d17c56b" href="javascript:void(0)">View Result</a>
```

[image]

this is my first
**I want to access the web page from the "Take Assessment" button rather than the "View Result" button. **Please help****

Comment: Take a look at Visual Event: https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2 there's probably an event handler attached after the fact.

Comment: @DanielB.Chapmanthank you, it did work but the "2 events were attached to elements not currently in the document". is there any way to access these?